# Why we cannot in general define the product of two submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, self-learning

why we can define product of two ideals of a commutative ring,but we can't in general define the product of two submodules?

[image]

[image]

```
                                          ——Introduction to Commutative algebra
```

Comment: What do you mean by product? I'm pretty sure we can define a product...

Comment: How do you multiply elements of a module with themselves?

Comment: I confused too,so I ask.

Comment: There are two operations in a ring: Addition of ring elements, and multiplication of ring elements. There are also two operations for a module: Addition of module elements, and the action of ring elements on module elements; there's no natural multiplication of module elements.

Comment: @program666: It's hard to answer without knowing what it is you're asking about.

Comment: @tomasz I ask why Michael Atiyah said:we can't in general define the product of two submodules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak b$ are ideals in a ring $R$, with elements $x$ and $y$ respectively, the product $xy$ makes sense: Multiplication is certainly defined for ring elements. Then (finite) sums of the form $\sum_i x_i y_i$ certainly make sense because $x_i y_i \in R$, and we can add ring elements.

This is *not* true, however, for modules: There is no natural way to form products of elements in modules. Remember that an $R$-module $M$ is an abelian group together with a certain action of $R$ on $M$; so given elements $m, n \in M$ and $r \in R$, the formulas $m + n$ and $rm$ make sense, while $mn$ does not.

So in short, the difference is that rings have a concept of multiplication, while modules have the concept of a ring action on module elements. There's not the same symmetry here.