# Is there an equivalent concept to tensor product as what the "sum" is to "direct sum"?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

As titled. For modules, we have the usual definition of "sum" and "direct sum" of submodules.

> Suppose $M$ is a $R$-module, and $A,B$ two submodules, such that $M=\{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}$. Then we say $M=A+B$ is the "sum". If we further have $A\cap B=\{0\}$, then we say $M=A\oplus B$ is the "internal direct sum".

We also have the concept of tensor product, which can be constructed by taking the direct sum and then taking quotients. For simplicity, we only state for vector spaces.

> For $k$-vector spaces $V, W$, the tensor product can be shown to satisfy
> $$V\otimes W= \left(\bigoplus_{(v,w)\in V\times W}k\right) \quad /\quad R,$$
> where $R$ is the subspace generated by linear and bilinear relations.

But do we have a "product" concept that is less strict than "tensor product", just like the "sum" is less strict than "direct sum"? If, in the quotient construction of tensor products, we replace "direct sum" with "sum", do we end up with such a less strict "product" somehow?

Hope it makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699653/why-we-cannot-in-general-define-the-product-of-two-submodules

Comment: My heuristics would be more that you can think of the sum as the image of the canonical morphism from the ("external") direct sum into your space. In particular in order to construct something similar you would need to have a canonical map from the tensor product of your submodules into your original module. However, I do not see an immediate canonical choice to do that as you would need some kind of internal multiplication (as mentioned in the answer given in the above comment)

Comment: @Enkidu Right. So such a concept would be definable for a two-sided $R$-algebra. But not general modules/vector spaces!

Comment: exactly! if you bake in a map from $V\otimes V\to V$ with some coherence properties it should work out. However, this will bake down to defining a (possible non-unital) algebra structure on $V$.